# Moving your own questions to another stackexchange community?

Tags: discussion, migration

How do I move my own question to another stackexchange community, or is that even advisable? Because the question could be answered by another community as well?

Comment: Some basic info on [migration](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/migration/info). Some basic info on [cross-posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info).

Comment: What about deleting the question on this community and then posting it again on another community ?

Comment: If you are aware of other SE Communities that might be able to answer, it's a good first step to check for previous Questions that answer or relate to yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What about deleting the question on this community and then posting it again on another community?

If your question did not yet receive any relevant attention on this site, there is no problem with deletion and reposting. You should not do this too often though.

If there is an answer with an upvote, you cannot delete.

If there are substantive comments or an answer without upvote you rather should not delete. It would be considered as a bit rude to destroy the work of others, although you might get away with it.

Whether it is advisable to move the question, will depend a lot on the specific question and other circumstances. There is dedicated functionality to migrate questions, thus it is considered as something that is advisable under certain circumstances.